# How to show Firestore serverTimestamp correctly depending on local

Tags: android, localization, google-cloud-firestore, datetime-format

I cant get this right and wonder how to show the Firestore `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` formatet individual depending  on what `local` the device has.

The Firestore `timestamp` look like this

> Sat Mar 10 19:42:32 GMT+01:00 2018

```
try {
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("Sat Mar 10 19:42:32 GMT+01:00 2018");
        txtCreationDate.setText(new Date(parsedDate.getTime()).toString());
     } catch (ParseException e) {
        txtCreationDate.setText("time error");
     }
```

If one user i USA create the date time object then if another user i Italy view it then the creation time must adjusted to his clock

I have read many pages about this but the dateFormat parser give me error only.
Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a model class named `MyClass` that has a `Date` field and public setters and getters, to get the date, please use the following code:

```
Date date = yourClass.getDate();
if (date != null) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
    String creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks no matter if I use `DateFormat.FULL`  or `DateFormat.LONG` there is no time part like  it say it should be [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) . There´s just like "January 12, 1952" - no time in there...I debug and see the `Date` is "Sat Mar 10 19:42:11 GMT+01:00 2018"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now with the new code?

Comment: Both answers to my Q is wrong, you both should use `getDateTimeInstance` instead of `getDateInstance` and getTimeInstance`

Comment: `getTimeInstance()` is getting only the time? Is not what you want? If you want both, let me know to update my answer with `getDateTimeInstance`, ok?

Comment: thanks Alex, little misunderstanding , I think of a `timestamp` as both date and time

Comment: it should be(i found out) `getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL, Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: Oh you're right. Just updated my anwer again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is simply use Date and setTimezine. The timestamp variable in my models are long variables and I use a code like this to convert the server time into a local one.

```
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("STRING FOR TIMEZONE"));
    String localizedToday = formatter.format(YOURDATEOBJECT);
```

Comment: But I don´t know the temezone, I mean I can see it in the String like "Sat Mar 10 19:42:32 GMT+01:00 2018" . Should a do some String manipulation here to get the GMT+01?

Comment: Where is you timestamp variable? Do you have a model that holds it?

Comment: It´s just and `java.util.Date` I just retrieved the Firestore `MyClass my = document.toObject(MyClass);` and it has a `Date` field for `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: Ok, so if it is a Java Data you can check the edit and pass it to the date formatter. You've saved your object with the serve data, in your app you check the user timezone and then generate a string with the server time converted to a local time.

Comment: Haven´t had time but will spin up some emulators with dif timezones and se how it goes

Comment: Both answers to my Q is wrong, you both should use `getDateTimeInstance` instead of `getDateInstance` and getTimeInstance`

Comment: I reckon the point is that you should use setTimeZone() but okay

Comment: Thanks no sorry maybe misunderstanding,  actually i dont have to set time zone with Alex answer , I just want to displace the timestamp

Comment: sure, no problem :)